# Which train stations in Brussels have bicycle access?

Tags: bicycles, brussels, train-stations

The NMBS/SNCB site says

> In Brussels, go to Midi or Nord stations. There is no access at Brussels Central, Brussels Chapelle or Brussels Congrès.

Which leaves out the other stations in Brussels, such as Brussel-Schuman. Which train stations in Brussels besides Midi and Nord have bicycle access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All other stations in Brussels are fine. The three stations mentioned where you cannot take a bicycle are the three station on the so-called North-South connection between Brussels South (=Midi) and Brussels North. This is by far the busiest stretch of railway in Belgium (according to some sources even in the world, but I have my doubts about that) and in those three stations all trains have to pass on only six tracks. They want to avoid delays there as much as possible. As loading and unloading bicycles often takes some time they forbid you to do so. An alternative is easy: just cycle to or from South or North. It is not far.

I don't have a link ready but know it from talking with railway personel about this exception

Comment: Thanks! I carried my bike on the Brussels-Luxembourg station without any problems.